# Lambda Query on Generic Type T

Tags: linq, generics, lambda

I have baase model class

```
public class BaseModel
{
  [Not Mapped]
  public string ExternalId;
}
```

Base model class is inherited by two child classes

```
public class ChildA : BaseModel
{
  public string ExternalId;
}

public class ChildB : BaseModel
{
  public string Name;
}
```

All child classes are inherited from BaseModel. I have declared ExternalId in some child classes so I can use in my abstract class for linq. Since these models are used in EF Model first and thats why in BaseModel its have attribute NotMapped so EF not generate this column.

and this is abstract class

```
public abstract class Test<T> : ITest<T> where T : BaseModel, new()
{
    protected virtual IEnumerable<T> TestMethod(IEnumerable<T> listModels)
    {
        var items = listModels.Where<T>(i => i.ExternalId != "ABC").ToList();
    }
}
```

How I can filter based on ExternalId of ChildA

Comment: _Why_ is it necessary to declare `ExternalId` in `ChildA` at all? It hides the base property and - well - causes your problem.

Comment: @RenéVogt I only need in ChildA and I just declared in BaseModel so I can use this property in my abstract method for linq.

Answer (score 0):

[Demo on fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Knysxi)

Your design have a problem like this

> 'ChildA.ExternalId' hides inherited member 'BaseModel.ExternalId'

You should not declare the `ExternalId` in `ChildA` class.

2. `TestMethod` is not returning value, So you should return instead.

> 'Test.TestMethod(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)': not all code paths return a value

You should fix like this

```
public interface ITest<T> where T : BaseModel, new()
{
     IEnumerable<T> TestMethod(IEnumerable<T> listModels);
}


public class Test<T> : ITest<T> where T : BaseModel, new()
{
    public IEnumerable<T> TestMethod(IEnumerable<T> listModels)
    {
        return listModels.Where<T>(i => i.ExternalId != "ABC").ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have seen your demo but I updated my question so might be you understand better now

Comment: Yes, you need to return `return listModels.Where<T>(i => i.ExternalId != "ABC").ToList();`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any hep @Arslan Pervaiz

Comment: no it doesnot helped fully. Might be we can discuss on chat room

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206688/discussion-between-phong-and-arslan-pervaiz).

Answer (score 0):

write same this :

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            testFinal tf = new testFinal();

            List<BaseModel> mylist = new List<BaseModel>()
            {
                new ChildA(){ ExternalId = "1"},
                new ChildB(){ ExternalId = "1"},
                new ChildA(){ ExternalId = "2"},
                new ChildA(){ ExternalId = "3"},
                new ChildA(){ ExternalId = "1"},
                new ChildB(){ ExternalId = "2"},
            };

            var result = tf.TestMethod(mylist);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }



    public class BaseModel
    {
        public string ExternalId;
    }


    public class ChildA : BaseModel
    {
        //public string ExternalId;
    }

    public class ChildB : BaseModel
    {
        public string Name;
    }


    public abstract class Test<T> : ITest<T> where T : BaseModel, new()
    {
        public IEnumerable<T> TestMethod(IEnumerable<T> listModels)
        {
            var items = listModels.Where<T>(i => i.ExternalId != "1").ToList();
            return items;
        }
    }


    public interface ITest<T> where T : BaseModel
    {
        IEnumerable<T> TestMethod(IEnumerable<T> listModels);
    }

    public class testFinal : Test<BaseModel>
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: You use BaseModel class in abstract class , your BaseModel class has ExternalId , and you use this field in Linq ! So , in your child classes , you should use this field and don't write again this field in child classes. It's wrong for your senario!

Comment: What do you mean I use that field in child. Can you please explain how I can access that is derived class and change the attribute

Comment: In ChildA , you hide ExtenalId of BaseModel !